# Symfony 4 не подкгружается статика из public

Tags: symfony

Запрашивая любую статику из папки public выдает ошибку 404.
все пути проверил и наличие файлов в директории.

> [Thu Apr 19 14:08:57 2018] 127.0.0.1:55234 [404]: /js/vue.js

Роуты = аннотация.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/{% if  app.environment  == 'dev' %}vue.js{% else %}vue.min.js{% endif %}"></script>
```

Comment: ResourceNotFoundException  NotFoundHttpException
HTTP 404 Not Found
No route found for "GET /js/vue.js" (from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/")

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы в `src` подставился корректный путь необходимо использовать функцию `asset`, которая вернёт путь до `public` + путь переданный в функцию.
Например, если есть файл `public/js/vue.js`, то подключить его можно так:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/vue.js') }}"></script>
```